# Character Arrays using

Tags: c, character-arrays

I want to use `scanf_s("%c\n", &arr[index])` to input once character at a time in a single line using `for`/`while` loop. I cannot figure out how to output the result. Below is the code.(I only want to use `scanf` statement. `fgets` way is easy.

```
printf("\nEnter the lowercase letters\n");
for (index = 0; index < size; index++)
{
    scanf_s("%c\n", &arr[index]);
    _getch();
}
printf("\nThanks"); 
for (index = 0; index < size; ++index)
{
    printf("%c/n", arr[index]);
}
```

It takes the input but exits out after thanks statement. I cannot figure out why. Although I have used a different method that works. It's just a variation I was trying.

Comment: Why are you using `_getch()` when you're also scanning with `scanf_s()`?  That's going to confuse the poor user who types `abcd` and sees only `ac`.  The `_getch()` is eating the `b` and `d`.  Also, newline is `\n` not `/n` — the third `printf()` has that as a typo.  Using `\n` at the end of an interactive input format string is a bad idea; the user has to type something that's not a white space character after the input to get the `scanf_s()` to return.

Comment: Try flushing your output after the second loop using `fflush(stdout)`

Comment: Apparently you have a Typo and your characters are not printing because the output buffer isn't flushed `%c/n` -> `%c\n`. Also `Thanks\n` would be better as it would print the first character in the next line, and don't use `getch()` it's not standard use `getchar()` instead as well as `scanf_s()` -> `scanf()` learn standard c so you can code for any platform. And as I told you you yeasterday `scanf(" %c", &arr[index]);` should do it without the `_getch()` thing.

Comment: sorry for the typos, i will correct it

Comment: @iharob: yes that is working only till it accepts character, but i will try using  flush for output

Comment: @Ricky just add the correct newline character and it will flush automatically.

Comment: @iharob: Now the confusion seems to be crystal clear. No more questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
scanf_s("%c\n", &arr[index]);
_getch();
```

To

```
scanf_s(" %c", &arr[index], 1);
```

When scanning a character(`%c`) or string(`%s`) using `scanf_s`, you must supply an additional value as a parameter which indicates the amount of characters to be scanned.
The space before `%c` discards all whitespace characters(newlines, spaces etc) including none before scanning a non-whitespace character.

Also, the `printf` in the loop has `/n` instead of `\n` for a newline.

Comment: Yes, i didnt consider the "amount of characters" criteria. That should do it. Thanks.

Comment: So apparently i tried your scanf statement::
for (index = 0; index < size; index++)
 {
  scanf_s(" %c", &arr[index], 1);
 }
 printf("\nThanks"); 
 fflush(stdout);
 for (index = 0; index < size; ++index)
 {
  printf("%c\n", arr[index]);
 }
And it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This code would probably work better:

```
int nchars;

printf("\nEnter the lowercase letters\n");
for (index = 0; index < size; index++)
{
    if (scanf_s("%c", &arr[index], 1) != 1)
        break;
}
printf("\nThanks\n");
nchars = index;  // Do not report on values that were not entered 
for (index = 0; index < nchars; ++index)
{
    printf("%c\n", arr[index]);
}
```

Note that when you use `scanf_s()` and the `%c` format (and `%s` and `%[…]`formats), it require a length as well as the pointer to the data storage location (two arguments for one conversion specification).  This tells the function how much space there is available to store the value.  Often, the length will not be 1; you'd use `scanf_s("%s", buffer, sizeof(buffer))` to read a string.

It is a good idea to check the return value from `scanf_s()` every time you use it so that you know whether it worked or not.

You can add extra criteria for breaking the loop, such as if the code reads a newline.

---

I also noted some problems in the comments — the issues are fixed in the code above.

> - Why are you using `_getch()` when you're also scanning with `scanf_s()`? That's going to confuse the poor user who types `abcd` and sees only `ac`. The `_getch()` is eating the `b` and `d`.
> - Also, newline is `\n` not `/n` — the third `printf()` has that as a typo.
> - Using `\n` at the end of an interactive input format string is a bad idea; the user has to type something that's not a white space character after the input to get the `scanf_s()` to return.

Comment: Now i know, i didn't think the solution other way round. Thanks that clears the problem